# importing with * (asterisk) versus as a namespace in python

Tags: python, namespaces

I know that its bad form to use `import *` in python, and I don't plan to make a habit of it. However I recently came across some curious behaviour that I don't understand, and wondered if someone could explain it to me.

Lets say I have three python scripts. The first, `first_script.py`, comprises:

```
MESSAGE = 'this is from the first script'

def print_message():
    print MESSAGE

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_message()
```

Obviously running this script gives me the contents of MESSAGE. I have a second script called `second_script.py`, comprising:

```
import first_script

first_script.MESSAGE = 'this is from the second script'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_script.print_message()
```

The behaviour (prints `this is from the second script`) makes sense to me. I've imported `first_script.py`, but overwritten a variable within its namespace, so when I call `print_message()` I get the new contents of that variable.

However, I also have `third_script.py`, comprising:

```
from first_script import *

MESSAGE = 'this is from the third script'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print MESSAGE
    print_message()
```

This first line this produces is understandable, but the second doesn't make sense to me. My intuition was that because I've imported into my main namespace via * in the first line, I have a global variable
called `MESSAGES`. Then in the second line I overwrite `MESSAGES`. Why then does the function (imported from the first script) produce the OLD output, especially given the output of `second_script.py`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with `Scope`. For a very excellent description of this, please see [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules)

For a detailed breakdown with tons of examples, see http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/python_reference/blob/master/tutorials/scope_resolution_legb_rule.ipynb

*Here's the details on your specific case:*

The `print_message` function being called from your third test file is being asked to print out some `MESSAGE` object. This function will use the standard `LEGB` resolution order to identify which object this refers to. `LEGB` refers to `Local, Enclosing function locals, Global, Builtins`.

1. Local - Here, there is no `MESSAGES` defined within the `print_message` function.
2. Enclosing function locals - There are no functions wrapping this function, so this is skipped.
3. Global - Any explicitly declared variables in the outer code. It finds `MESSAGE` defined in the global scope of the `first_script` module. *Resolution then stops, but i'll include the others for completeness.*
4. Built-ins - The list of python built-ins, [found here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id).

   So, you can see that resolution of the variable `MESSAGE` will cease immediately in `Global`, since there was something defined there.

Another resource that was pointed out to me for this is [Lexical scope vs Dynamic scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping), which may help you understand scope better.

HTH

Comment: So I guess I didn't overwrite the global variable in my `third_script.py`?

Comment: Remember, each module will have a globally defined `MESSAGE`. Using wildcard imports, you no longer have access to the original `MESSAGE`, since you redefine it in third_script. Remember, strings are immutable in python, so the old `MESSAGE` is thrown away, and is redefined as a new variable, causing the print_message to refer to it's internal reference to the old `MESSAGE`.

Answer (score 2):

`import module`, `from module import smth` and `from module import *`can have different use cases.

#### The simpler:

```
import tools
```

loads the `tools` module and adds a reference to it in the local namespace (also named `tools`). After that you can access *any* of the tools references by prepending `tools` to them like for example `tools.var1`

Variant:

```
import tools as sloot
```

Does exactly the same, but you use the alias to access the references from the module (eg: `sloot.var1`). It is mainly used for module having well known aliases like `import numpy as np`.

#### The other way

```
from tools import foo
```

directly imports some symbols from the `tools` module in the current namespace. That means that you can only use the specified symbols by they do not need to be qualified. A nice use case is when you could import a symbol from different modules giving same functionalities. For example

```
try:
    from mod1 import foo
except ImportError:
    from mod2 import foo

...
foo()      # actually calls foo from mod1 if available else foo from mod2
```

This is commonly use as a portability trick.

The danger:

```
from tools import *
```

It is a common idiom, but may not do what you expect if the module does not document it. In fact, it imports all the public symbols from the module, by default all the symbols that have no initial `_` which can contain unwanted things. In addition, a module can declare a special variable `__all__` which is assumed to declare the public interface, and in that case only the symbols contained in `__all__` will be imported.

Example:

mod.py

```
__all__ = ['foo', 'bar']

def baz(x):
    return x * 2

def foo():
    return baz('FOO')

def bar():
    return baz('BAR')
```

You can use (assuming mod.py is accessible)

```
from mod import *

print(foo())    # should print FOOFOO

# ERROR HERE
x = baz("test") # will choke with NameError: baz is not defined
```

while

```
import mod

print(mod.baz("test"))     # will display as expected testtest
```

So you should only use `from tools import *` if the documentation of the `tools` module declares it to be safe and lists the actually imported symbols.

Comment: Disclaimer: I had prepared this answer for another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53836521/3545273) which was close as a duplicate of this one. As I think it is more exhaustive than the current answers, I have posted it here, even if I know that this one is now quite old.

Answer (score 1):

Direct assignment changes the reference of an object, but modification does not. For example,

```py
a = []
print(id(a))
a = [0]
print(id(a))
```

prints two different IDs, but

```py
a = []
print(id(a))
a.append(0)
print(id(a))
```

prints the same ID.

In `second_script.py`, the assignment merely modifies `first_script`, which is why both `first_script.py` and `second_script.py` can locate the same attribute `MESSAGE` of `first_script`. In `third_script.py`, the direct assignment changes the reference of `MESSAGE`; therefore, after the assignment, the variable `MESSAGE` in `third_script.py` is a different variable from `MESSAGE` in `first_script.py`.

Consider the related example:

**first_script.py**

```py
MESSAGE = ['this is from the first script']

def print_message():
    print(MESSAGE)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_message()
```

**third_script.py**

```py
from first_script import *

MESSAGE.append('this is from the third script')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MESSAGE)
    print_message()
```

In this case, `third_script.py` prints two identical messages, demonstrating that names imported by `import *` can still be modified.