# How is the use of import modulename related to namespace of imported module?

Tags: python, import, namespaces

This is an extract from a textbook :

**When using the import *modulename* form of import, the namespace of the imported module becomes available to , but not part of,the importing module.**

I am not able to understand ,What exactly is namespace and what do they mean by ''namespace becomes available to but not part of importing module''?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [importing with \* (asterisk) versus as a namespace in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767300/importing-with-asterisk-versus-as-a-namespace-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you are doing

```
import os
```

you can now access members of os, for example

```
os.path
```

but you cant access `path` directly as it's not in your namespace, it's in the `os` namespace.
It's the difference between

```
import os
```

and

```
from os import *
```

(the latter will import everything into your namespace and should generally be avoided to not accidentally overwrite methods)